# Django DeleteView redirect to variable location

Tags: python, django

I want to be able to use the DeleteView CBV in Django 1.5c1 (including the confirmation page), but have the user be redirected to where he/she clicked the object.

For example, here is a rough outline of my site's structure based around Events:

```
/events/week/2013/03/   - ListView, shows 3rd week of 2013's Events
/events/month/2013/01/  - ListView, shows January of 2013's Events
/events/year/2013/      - ListView, show 2013's Events
/events/53/             - DetailView, shows a specific Event
```

On any of these Events listings, I could have an Event that appears on them all. Rather than having an Event's URL depend on the list that the user has navigated from (e.g. /events/year/2013/53/), I've chosen to have the Event be served on an independent URL (e.g. /events/53/).

**With that context, I want to be able to have a delete button on my Event's DetailView that redirects back to the ListView that the user navigated from.**

I've considered:

- Middleware that will look at the previous URL and add it to the session if it's a ListView in my URLconf. This has several disadvantages, one of which being the need to whitelist every possible location that an Event's DetailView can be clicked from.
- On the delete button on DetailView, append `?next={{ request.META.HTTP_REFER }}` to the DeleteView's URL and adding it to the delete form somehow, but the whole referrer's URL is passed (e.g. /events/53/delete/?next=www.site.com/events/year/2013/).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this as a mixin:

```
class RedirectURLView(View):

    def get_success_url(self):
        next_url = self.request.GET.get('next')

        if next_url:
            return next_url
        else:
            return super(RedirectURLView, self).get_success_url()
```

then append `?next={{ request.path }}` to the urls